# Best strategy for conflicting dependencies in libraries and applications in Android

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, libraries, conflict

I am working on a library that will be integrated into multiple in-house applications.
The library I am working on uses another in-house library, for example, **inhouse-lib:0.1.15**
When we implemented our library into one of the in-house applications, we came across a crash because the inhouse application uses **inhouse-lib:0.1.20**

This led to a conflict with a method, where our library had a method with 4 params, while the in-house application using the newer inhouse-lib had a method with 5 params.

I fixed this by updating our **inhouse-lib:0.1.15** to be **0.1.20**
My question is, what would be the best strategy to prevent issues like this in the future?
inhouse-lib gets updated quite a lot, and the applications would update quite frequently. So how can we prevent them from updating causing issues with our library, which may use older versions and get updated less frequently?

Is the only solution to request the inhouse-lib team to ensure backward compatibility?

Hope it makes sense.
Looking forward to any answers.
Thank you